Return parenthesis location errors when place in different location
I was getting an error that the code was not reachable. This is the code I was using:
  return
  (
        <div>
          <img src={myProfileData.profilePicUrl} alt={`${myProfileData.name} smiling`} height="200" />
          <h2>My Profile</h2>
          <h3>Name</h3>
          <p>{myProfileData.name}</p>
          <h3>Age</h3>
          <p>{myProfileData.age}</p>
          <h3>Bio</h3>
          <p>{myProfileData.bio}</p>
          <h3>Birthday</h3>
          <p>{myProfileData.birthday}</p>
          <h3>Interests</h3>
          <p>{myProfileData.interests.join(', ')}</p>
        </div>
  );

I fixed it by using the following code:
  return(
        <div>
          <img src={myProfileData.profilePicUrl} alt={`${myProfileData.name} smiling`} height="200" />
          <h2>My Profile</h2>
          <h3>Name</h3>
          <p>{myProfileData.name}</p>
          <h3>Age</h3>
          <p>{myProfileData.age}</p>
          <h3>Bio</h3>
          <p>{myProfileData.bio}</p>
          <h3>Birthday</h3>
          <p>{myProfileData.birthday}</p>
          <h3>Interests</h3>
          <p>{myProfileData.interests.join(', ')}</p>
        </div>
  );

Why does:
return(
);

work but:
return
(
);

does not?

Because ASI puts a semicolon between return and ( unless they're on the same line. Note this has nothing to do with React.
